# Experiencing Problems Integrating Zoom SDK with React

Tags: reactjs, zoom-sdk

## I'm encountering an issue while integrating the Zoom SDK into my React app. When I attempt to join a Zoom meeting with both my camera and microphone turned off, I encounter an error. However, there are no issues when I join a meeting with both the camera and microphone turned on.

Here are the details of the problem:

**Issue:**
When attempting to join a Zoom meeting with either the camera or microphone off, an error occurs, preventing me from joining the meeting successfully.

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect to be able to join a Zoom meeting even when my camera or microphone is turned off. It should not cause any errors.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Open the React app.
- Join a Zoom meeting.
- Ensure that either the camera or microphone (or both) are turned off.
- Observe the error preventing me from joining the meeting.

**Additional Information:**

- React Version: 18.2
- Zoom SDK Version: @zoomus/websdk": 2.16.0
- Browser: Google Chrome
- Operating System: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

**This is the whole component**

```
function ZoomMeeting() {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const { ZoomMtg } = await import("@zoomus/websdk");

    ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib("https://source.zoom.us/2.16.0/lib", "/av");

    ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
    ZoomMtg.prepareWebSDK();
    ZoomMtg.i18n.load("en-US");
    ZoomMtg.i18n.reload("en-US"); 
    ZoomMtg.generateSDKSignature({
      meetingNumber: payload.meetingNumber,
      role: payload.role,
      sdkKey: payload.sdkKey,
      sdkSecret: payload.sdkSecret,
      success: function (signature) {
        ZoomMtg.init({
          leaveUrl: payload.leaveUrl,
          isSupportAV: true,
          success: function (data) {
            ZoomMtg.join({
              meetingNumber: payload.meetingNumber,
              signature: signature.result,
              sdkKey: payload.sdkKey,
              userName: payload.userName,
              userEmail: payload.userEmail,
              passWord: payload.passWord,
              tk: "",
              success: function () {
                console.log("JOINED");
              },
              error: function (error) {
                console.log("INNER INNER ERROR => ", error);
              },
            });
          },
          error: function (error) {
            console.log("INNER ERROR => ", error);
          },
        });
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("OUTER ERROR => ", error);
      },
    });
  }, []);
  return <div>ZoomMeeting</div>;
}
```

**This is the error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNBhx.png)

**This is the exact error that appears in the console.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q015a.png)

**I appreciate any insights or solutions you can provide to help resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for your assistance!**

- Carefully reviewed the Zoom SDK documentation to ensure I'm following the correct integration steps.
- Experimented with different configurations in my React app to see if there was a specific setting causing the issue.
- Sought advice from the ChatGPT to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you